# How Would I Insert A String With Commas Into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, string, insert, mysqli

I am trying to insert a string variable from a form into mysql but it keeps giving me an error, and within the error it cuts off part of the statement, so I assume its an issue with the fact that there are commas in the string...

**Here Is Some Sample Code:**

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {
  $startcode = $_POST['messagefield'];
  $replaced = preg_replace( '/\\\\(?="|\')/', '', $startcode );
  /* NEW CODE */
  /*selectleads[] is now an array of your database's ids. 
    You can now run a query to get whatever information you 
    need. In this case, you want the email addresses, so:
   */
  $collectedleads = $_POST['selectleads'];
  $emailaddylist = array();
  foreach ($collectedleads as $id) {

  $colname_rs_SelectedLeads = $id;

mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
$query_rs_SelectedLeads = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE `Id` = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_SelectedLeads, "text"));
$rs_SelectedLeads = mysql_query($query_rs_SelectedLeads, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_SelectedLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_SelectedLeads);
$totalRows_rs_SelectedLeads = mysql_num_rows($rs_SelectedLeads);

$emailaddylist[] = $row_rs_SelectedLeads['Email'];
$nameaddylist[] = $row_rs_SelectedLeads['FullName'];
  }
  /*Now you have an array of email addresses that correspond to 
    the ids you were sent via $_POST.
   */
  $emailaddystring = implode(", ", $emailaddylist);
  $nameaddystring = implode(", ", $nameaddylist);

  echo $emailaddystring . "</br>";
  echo $nameaddystring;

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO PendingEmails (to, NameTo, subject, message) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
                       GetSQLValueString($emailaddystring, "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($nameaddystring, "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['subjectfield'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($replaced, "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());

  /*$insertGoTo = "View Folder.php?Folder=" . $_POST['Folder'] . "";
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));*/

mysql_free_result($rs_SelectedLeads);

}
```

**And Here Is The Actual Form:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="form" id="sendemailform">
          <fieldset>
          <div class="emailtablecontainer">
          <table width="525" border="0" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td><label>To:</label></td>
    <td><select data-placeholder="Select Lead(s) To Email..." multiple="true" class="chzn-container-multi" name="selectleads[]"style="width:505px;">
            <?php
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['Id']; ?>"><?php echo $row_rsAllLeads['FullName']?></option>
            <?php
} while ($row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsAllLeads);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rsAllLeads, 0);
      $row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads);
  }
?>
          </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Subject:</label></td>
    <td><input class="inputs" name="subjectfield" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Message:</label></td>
    <td><textarea id="sendemailtextarea" name="messagefield"></textarea></td>
    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'sendemailtextarea',
    {
        toolbar : 'SendEmailToolbar',
        uiColor: '#94B0C1',
        height : '62'
    });
    </script>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<input class="submitemailbuttonsprite submitemailbutton1" name="submitemail" type="submit" value="Send Email(s)">
          </fieldset>
          <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form">
          </form>
```

**And Here Is The Error:**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to, NameTo, subject, message) VALUES (''Praesent.luctus.Curabitur@velturpis.edu,' at line 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: *to* is a key word. back-tick it (or change it). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: The syntax error reported is due to the use of the reserved keyword `TO`. Enclose it in backticks to use as a column/table name.

Comment: I tried back-ticking to and got this `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'daaghewi@gmail.com, eu.nibh@posuere.edu'', ''asdfqphgp, Jenette Smith'', ''asdf'' at line 1`

Comment: you have quotes all over the place. there needs to be one on each side of each string. or use a prepared statement.

Comment: i just took out all quotes and it worked fine :)  thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the sql you are producing has too many single-quotes( ' )

```
(''Praesent.luctus.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the commas between the values:

```
$string = 'string with commas\,string with more commas\,end of the string';

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (row_name) VALUES (:string)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(': row_name'=>$string);
```

Comment: you dont need to escape commas in strings

Comment: in strings not but he tries to insert a comma separated value which may throw an error. Note that he is not using PDO which is a suggestion

Comment: No, commas inside a string do not throw an error.  Not in PHP nor in SQL.  Sorry, this is not true.

Comment: How can you then explain single quotes and a commas being a delimiters in SQL statements which, if not used properly will divide the statement into pieces?